# Trying to log into a site with the cURL extension of PHP

Tags: php, curl

Basically, I'm trying to log into a site. I've got it logging in, but the site redirects to another part of the site, and upon doing so, it redirects my browser as well.

For example:

It successfully logs into `http://example.com/login.php`

But then my browser goes to `http://mysite.com/site.php?page=loggedin`

I just want it to return the contents of the page, not be redirected to it.

How would I do this?

As requested, here is my code

```
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init(); 

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginURL); 

//Some setopts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWREDIRECT, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERRER, $referrer);

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

Comment: Which is the page of which you want to get content?

Comment: `http://example.com/site.php?page=loggedin`

Comment: Can you post some example code of what is giving you this behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by 'your browser'? I don't understand what's going on here.

Comment: Alex JL, I'm loading the page in my browser. And now that I think of it, it might be loading a meta refresh. Is there anyway to stop that, if that's the case?

Comment: Any chance to ask a site owner for less complicated way to share info? An RSS with HTTP basic auth, for example?

Comment: That'd be nice, Col. Shrapnel, but I doubt it. He's pretty hard to get in touch with, and quite lazy. I just need to scrape his site for some information and then make a list according to information found on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The webpage was echoing a meta refresh, and since I was echoing the output, my browser followed.

Removed the `echo $output;` and it no longer does that.

I feel kind of dumb for not recognizing that in the beginning.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Using cURL you have to find the redirect and follow it, then return that page's content. I'm not sure why your browser would be redirecting unless you have some weird header code that you are returning from the login page.

Answer (score 0):

set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to false.

```
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , FALSE);
```

this might help you.